# How to merge two subsets of a pandas dataframe and sort by original index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe:[Original Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFDbs.png)

I then performed two operations on this dataframe to filter out some cells. This gives me the following two dataframes which are derived from the original dataframe:[first filtered dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPV71.png), [second filtered dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l58RS.png)

How can I merge these two dataframes together and sort it by original index? Here is the example result of what I would like to do: [merged dataframe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdHik.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since they share no intersecting indexes between the two data frames, you can simply concatenate them and sort them by index like this:

```py
merged = pandas.concat(first_filtered_df1, second_filtered_df2).sort_index()
```

If `Index` is the label of the header of the column and not a real index then:

```py
merged = pandas.concat(first_filtered_df1, second_filtered_df2).sort_values(by=['Index'])
```